# Recieved text message about package I didn't order?

Tags: scams, mailing

I recieved a text message which claims to be from DHL Express. This message contains a delivery date and what appears to be a tracking number. I went on the DHL website and entered the tracking number, and indeed it is tied to an item. The package is coming from a foreign country and the destination area is my city, but I don't see my particular address anywhere on that page (though that is the destination area, it could still be that it's destined for my address, they just don't show it there). What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Did they text message contain a link? It could be [this](http://securitywatch.pcmag.com/mobile-security/327148-mobile-threat-monday-android-trojan-disguised-as-dhl-tracker)

Comment: If you are not expecting something, what is the downside of ignoring the message?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not about personal finance

Answer (score 2):

Have you never gotten a wrong number before?  The person sending the package mis-typed the phone-number for the recipient.  There's not a lot to be done.  The correct recipient won't get the warning about his package, but that won't be the worst thing that happens to him today.